# Configuring Experience manager database

Tags: siteedit

Can we use same content delivery database for experience manager or we need to create separate database for experience manager because both database has same structure.

Comment: you probably could use the same credentials, but i'm not sure it would be a good idea to use the same database.

Answer (score 10):

The Session Preview database has the same structure (tables, etc) as the 'normal' broker database (Content Data store), but it should be a separate database. So your staging website uses 2 databases: one 'normal' broker database and one Session Preview database.

See the docs for more information ([login required](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)): http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539

Answer (score 1):

Your Session Preview database should definitely be separate from the normal Broker database.

Although there are Session Preview specific tables (such as `PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS` and `PREVIEW_SESSIONS`), there are a number of other tables (such as `PAGE` and `PAGE_CONTENT`) that are needed by **both** the normal Content Delivery functionality and the Session Preview functionality. Therefore, we need to have two separate databases to handle this.